# JSONException: No value for photo

Tags: java, android, api, flickr

I'm using the Flickr API to get my app to display images depending on user search. I keep getting this error: `JSONException: No value for photo`

The call to get the photo:

```
public ArrayList<Category> processResults(Response response) {
    ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        String jsonData = response.body().string();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            JSONObject flickrJSON = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            //json data
            JSONArray photoJSON = flickrJSON.getJSONArray("photo");
        }
    }
}
```

the json format is this:

```
{
    photos: { page: 1, 
              pages: 2165, 
              perpage: 100, 
              total: "216413", 
              photo: [ { id: "37095719122",
              ....
    }
}
```

Comment: the json format is this                                                                        
 photos: {
page: 1,
pages: 2165,
perpage: 100,
total: "216413",
photo: [
{
id: "37095719122",

Comment: Since `new JSONObject()` accepts the string, I am guessing its a valid JSON object and in that case, the string should start with `{` and not with `photos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `new JSONObject()` part of your code works fine, its safe to assume that the JSON object you are getting is valid and in that case your actuall JSON object must look something like this :

```
{
    photos: { page: 1, 
              pages: 2165, 
              perpage: 100, 
              total: "216413", 
              photo: [ { id: "37095719122",
              .....
    }
}
```

The variable `flickerJSON` would contain this whole object and the only field it has is `photos`, while the `photo` field you are trying to access is an inner field of `photos` object.

Hence, you can access the `photo` field like this :

```
JSONArray photoJSON = flickrJSON.getJSONObject("photos").getJSONArray("photo");
```

Comment: Thanks you this worked. However my app is now displaying the imageUrl instead of the actual image. Any ideas on how i can solve this, I'm new to Android sorry

Comment: You need to download that image using that URL. Also, since that would be an entirely different topic, you might want to mark this answer as the accepted one.