# How to get Channel Id from Youtube Api ? it shows this error " JSONException: No value for channelId"

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm using Youtube Api to get channel Id,but i'm getting that Error.

i read this answer [JSONException: No value for photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258683/jsonexception-no-value-for-photo) 
but it couldn't solve my problem.

This is some of JSON code.

```
   {  
   "kind":"youtube#activityListResponse",
   "etag":"\"8jEFfXBrqiSrcF6Ee7MQuz8XuAM/OMMhc8F-t0SORJfXv_Owv4A3N_g\"",
   "nextPageToken":"CAUQAA",
   "pageInfo":{  
      "totalResults":20,
      "resultsPerPage":5
   },
   "items":[  
      {  
         "kind":"youtube#activity",
         "etag":"\"8jEFfXBrqiSrcF6Ee7MQuz8XuAM/WUtPyfC60sUnCViYyIHtr7rKu5E\"",
         "id":"VTE1NjcxMTI0MzYxNDAyNDEzMTcwNzczOTI=",
         "snippet":{  
            "publishedAt":"2019-08-29T21:00:36.000Z",
            "channelId":"UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
            "title":"Android Studio 3.5, Cloud Run Button, BigQuery Terraform module",
```

and this is the java code

```
   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                Log.i("jsonObject ", jsonObject.toString());
                String items= jsonObject.getString("items");

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(items);
                for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("ID",jsonPart.getString("channelId"));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

i expect it would show this result in logcat

```
    "channelId":"UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
```

but its showing this error "JSONException: No value for channelId"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONArray` you want has the name `items`, not `snippets`.

You have to do something like that:

```
String items = jsonObject.getString("items");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(items);

for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject snippet = new JSONObject(jsonPart.getString("snippet"))
    Log.i("ID",snippet.getString("channelId"));
}
```

Comment: sorry, i did it but still the problem is exist

Comment: its showing this error again "JSONException: No value for snippets"

Comment: Yes, because it is `snippet`, not `snippets`